# How to get first key and value of map in IE11

Tags: javascript

What's the vanilla alternative for IE11 of:

```
Map myMap = new Map();
...
let firstKey = myMap.keys().next().value;
let firstVector = myMap.values().next().value;
```

These also don't work:

```
let keys = myMap.keys();
let firstKey = keys[0];
let firstVector = Object.values(myMap)[0];
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-map

Comment: So, basically it returns the first item from a `Map` (in order of insertion). You can just replace this with manual check and store the first inserted key somewhere separately.

Comment: Did you look to see if there is a polyfill?

Answer (score 0):

You can try polyfill. With webpack and Encore you can do it.

Tutorial:
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore/babel-polyfills

add core-js polyfill before your code.